# Pyinstaller offline pip install does not work

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I'm trying to install `pyinstaller-develop.tar.gz` in offline mode, i have already installed all dependencies, such as `future, setuptools,pefile,macholib,altgraph` but i'm getting `SSLError, self signed certificate in certificate chain... :/simple/setuptools`. I fail to understand this because when running `pip list`, `setuptools` seeems to be installed.

Comment: Try `pip install pyinstaller-develop.tar.gz --no-index`.

Comment: I'm getting `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools` which is odd because i have it in `pip list` and i also have it working outside the virtualenvironment

Comment: Hmm, that's indeed strange. Are you in a virtual env? Can you run e.g. `python -c "import setuptools; print(setuptools.__version__)"` to print the version?

Comment: @hoefling, yeah, i did `python` from cmd and then `import setuptools` and no error pops up. It's even stranger that i used the exact `.tar.gz` to install it to the global python and it worked, also, `setuptools` is the same version.

Comment: I have the same problem that it errors about setuptools requirement not being satisfied.

Comment: You can work around this by  manually running the setup.py file instead of relying on pip. See description on PyInstaller issue [#4557](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4557)